# How can I mix multiple and optional arguments in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, tuples

I want to write function with default and multiple arguments. Now I have somethink like this:

```
def make_pizza(size=10, *toppings):
    for t in toppings:
        print("-",t)

    print('Pizza has', size, 'cm')
```

and later I try to call:

```
make_pizza(30, 'pepperoni')
make_pizza('pepperoni')
make_pizza(50, 'cheese', 'cucumber', 'chilli')
```

but results looks bad:

`- pepperoni
Pizza has 30 cm
Pizza has pepperoni cm
- cheese
- cucumber
- chilli
Pizza has 50 cm`

What should I do, if I want print '10' instead pepperoni in third line?

Answer (score 4):

Well, since you're using Python 3, the easiest is to have `size` be a [*keyword-only argument*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/):

```
def make_pizza(*toppings, size=10):
    for t in toppings:
       print("-",t)

    print('Pizza has', size, 'cm')
```

Notice how the `size=10` must *follow* the `*toppings`.

Now, to specify the `size` you need to name it explicitly:

```
make_pizza('pepperoni') 
make_pizza('pepperoni', size=30)
```

---

Another alternative would be to check the *type* of `size` and if it is an instance of say [`numbers.Number`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html#numbers.Number), then assume it is the size, otherwise it is a topping, and should be added to the beginning of the `toppings` tuple... and the size should be reset to default.

Or you could always specify the size.

However I'd prefer the keyword-only arguments as this is exactly the kind of problem they were meant to solve.

Comment: Beat me to it! This is here first and is the correct answer. So +1

Comment: Hi.

Thanks for response, I've tried it earlier, and problem was with '50' on ingridients list, so thanks for resolve ;)